# bootstrap grid xs becomes 18 columns not 12 columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-8">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-lg-8</div>
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">.col-xs-6 .col-lg-4</div>
```

I have read in bootstrap grid, the grids should be equal to the 12 columns totally. but in bootstrap site itself in grid examples they have mentioned above code.. col-xs-12 and col xs-6 equals to becomes 18 but not 12. please clarify this confusion .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The markup in your question is "correct", but probably doesn't explain why. Basically, if you choose to use more than 12 columns, any extra columns after the initial 12 will wrap onto the next line. For example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">...</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">...</div>
</div>
```

Will produce a similar result to the following:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">...</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">...</div>
</div>
```

Both methods are allowed, but you have much more control over the look and style of your page when using the `row, columns, row, columns` method in the second example.

Read More Here: [Bootstrap Column Wrapping](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping)

> If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-9">.col-xs-9</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">.col-xs-4<br>Since 9 + 4 = 13 &gt; 12, this 4-column-wide div gets wrapped onto a new line as one contiguous unit.</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6<br>Subsequent columns continue along the new line.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap does only allow for 12 columns total.

Why the example itself shows 18 also eludes me but the thing to consider is that if more than 12 columns are defined the next group of columns is pushed to the next line. This is normally easily shown with lg or sm or md.

With xs columns, the width is completely auto. This could possibly mean that you can define 18 on one line and they would all auto width. I say your best bet is to play around with xs and see why bootstrap provides it as an example of 18.

I would focus on the width (auto) and the definition of other column types as a comparison to xs. That is the key.

Answer (score 1):

Your read Bootstrap grid but you didn't read Bootstrap grid CSS. It's not possible to Bootstrap grid equals to becomes 18 columns. Below the Bootstrap grid CSS.

```
.col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, col-lg-12{
  width: 100%;
  float: left:
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  min-height: 1px;
}
.col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, col-lg-6{
  width: 50%;
  float: left:
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  min-height: 1px;
}
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, col-lg-1{
  width: 8.3333%;
  float: left:
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  min-height: 1px;
}
```

Three difference @meida query CSS width are same (100/12).

Answer (score -3):

You can don't use `col-xs` becuase in default  equal to 12 column
use this code below

```
<div class="container">  
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">.col-lg-8 .col-sm-6 .col-xs-12</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">.col-lg-4 .col-sm-6 .col-xs-12</div>
</div>
</div>
```

this code it is correct and not contain the any errors

may be you don't used the `container` class

and when you use one `row` this means you can put in 12 columns 
you used one row must be the collection of each columns don't exceed 12 column
for example `clo-lg-8` + `col-lg-4` = `col-lg-12` this is true
but if the collection of column less than 12 column don't problem. but should not exceed 12 column.

in your example `col-xs-12` + `col-xs-6` = `col-xs-18` this is error because you used one `row` and putted all column if first div and you can put another colimn in that row you must decrease the `col-xs-12` until can add column in second div to that row.

Comment: This is a bit hard to understand.

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer to the question... For one, the question is about **why** the example has 18 columns. Second, you still have `col-xs-12` followed by `col-xs-6` in your "solution".